# Accurate market search via intent

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play

I have a button that when clicked will search the market for an app. I have two examples. In the first example the user is brought to a search result page in the market app. In the second example the user is brought to the correct page but the browser is used. How can I change this code to bring me to my intended results?

Let me provide code (nevermind that the app names are different):

Example A:

```
   Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   i.setData(Uri.parse("market://search?q=com.amazon.kindle"));
   startActivity(i);
```

Results of Example A:

[image]

Example B:

```
  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  i.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.netflix.mediaclient"));
  startActivity(i);
```

Results of Example B:

[image]

Intended results:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
market://details?id=com.amazon.kindle
```

More info: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#marketintent